# Making a dialog where the user can choose either a file or a folder

Tags: matlab, user-interface, user-experience, filechooser, matlab-gui

In MATLAB, there's a function that prompts the user to choose one or more files - [`uigetfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html), and there's another function which allows the user to choose a folder - [`uigetdir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetdir.html).

I would like to provide the user an ability to choose **either** a file **or** a folder, using a single window, as this is important for the UX I'm trying to create.

So far, the only solution I found that uses the above functions<sup>[1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53526#comment_110820)</sup> requires an additional step of asking the user what type of entity they would like to select, in advance, and calling the appropriate function accordingly - which I find inconvenient.

So how can I have a dialog which allows me to select either one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a Java component for this, specifically [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), and make sure that we provide it with the `FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES` selection flag.

```
%% Select entity:
jFC = javax.swing.JFileChooser(pwd);
jFC.setFileSelectionMode(jFC.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
returnVal = jFC.showOpenDialog([]);
switch returnVal
  case jFC.APPROVE_OPTION
    fName = string(jFC.getSelectedFile());
  case jFC.CANCEL_OPTION
    % do something with cancel
  case jFC.ERROR_OPTION
    % do something with error
  otherwise
    throw(MException("fileFolderChooser:unsupportedResult", ...
                     "Unsupported result returned from JFileChooser: " + returnVal + ...
                     ". Please consult the documentation of the current Java version (" + ...
                     string(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version")) + ")."));
end

%% Process selection:
switch true % < this is just some trick to avoid if/elseif
  case isfolder(fName)
    % Do something with folder
  case isfile(fName)
    % Do something with file
  otherwise
    throw(MException('fileFolderChooser:invalidSelection',...
                     'Invalid selection, cannot proceed!'));
end
```

This produces a familiar-looking dialog as follows, which works exactly as expected:

[image: Selection dialog]

`JFileChooser` has a variety of interesting settings like [multi-selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled-boolean-) and [showing hidden files/folders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileHidingEnabled-boolean-), as well as standard settings like [changing the dialog title](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogTitle-java.lang.String-), the button [texts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setApproveButtonText-java.lang.String-) and [tooltips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setApproveButtonToolTipText-java.lang.String-), etc. It can also be used as either an "Open" dialog or a "Save" dialog simply by [setting a value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogType-int-).

Tested on R2018a, with Java 1.8.0_144 (output of `java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version")`).

Comment: Hacking MATLAB eh